# changing classes and adding click event

Tags: jquery

I am changing my current class on the first click event and then I would like the class it was replaced with to have its own click event. Here is my current attempt:

```
$(".originalButton").on("click", function(){
  // THIS WORKS, it changes the class.
  $(this).closest(".questions").find(".originalButton").removeClass("originalButton").addClass("correctButton").off("click");
});
```

Now right under event handler I added this:

```
$(".correctButton").on("click", function(){
  debugger;

});
```

Ideally I would have something else instead of debugger, but at this point the event isn't even firing when the `correctButton` class button is clicked, even though when I inspect element the class updated properly (from the first click event).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use event delegation as you are adding/removing classes dynamically . Use:

```
$(".questions").on("click",'.correctButton', function(){
   debugger;
});
```

Comment: He should bind ".originalButton" with delegation, too. If not, the second time both events will be fired.

Comment: @Johnny5: not sure whether OP needs that. also OP is removing the click event when adding newClass

Comment: not exactly the `body` tag, he can just use the immediate parent of `.correctButton`

Comment: @Zafarbek: yes...may be element with class `questions`

Comment: of course if he have a selector for the parent. but either ways work good.